# pipe to kill command

Tags: unix, kill

I am trying this out in termnial:

```
/tmp ps x | grep -m1 firefox | cut -d' ' -f1 | kill -KILL    
kill: not enough arguments
```

How can I pipe the pid to kill?

I tried this, didn't work

```
 /tmp ps x | grep -m1 firefox | kill -KILL $(cut -d' ' -f1)
cut: -: Input/output error
kill: not enough arguments
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use xargs. This reads the output of command1 and use it as the arguments to run command2:

```
command1 | xargs command2
```

In your case

```
ps x | grep -m1 firefox | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs kill -KILL
```